# Unexpected output in string comparison

Tags: c++, string, templates

In the following CPP code, `isGreater()` function does its job right for integers. However, it does not produce the correct result for strings. My initial guess was that as `std:: string ::compare()` method has not been used so I created a specialized `isGreater()` template method for strings and first `cout` still produces output as 1. My thought is that it must compare strings alphabetically. But, I don't think so it's doing that. Second and third `cout` statements provide correct output i.e. integers in comparison and strings alphabetically. What exactly is going on in `isGreater()` for strings?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
bool isGreater(T x1, T x2)
{
    return (x1 > x2);
}

template <>
bool isGreater(string x1, string x2)
{
    return (x1.compare(x2));
}

int main()
{
    cout << isGreater("AAAA", "ZZZZ") << endl; //First cout
    cout << isGreater(5, 10) << endl; //Second cout
    string str1 = "AAA";
    string str2 = "ZZZZZ";
    cout << str1.compare(str2) << endl; //Third cout
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::string::operator>` is perfectly fine as well. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `isGreater("AAAA", "ZZZZ")` doesn't call your `std::string` specialization. It calls the general templated function using *pointers* (`const char*`), and you compare those pointers instead of the strings.

You need to add a specialization (or overload) taking the pointer arguments if you want to use literal strings.

---

As for the `std::string` specialization, the [`std::string::compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) function doesn't [return](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare#Return_value) what you think it does.

It returns a "true" (non-zero) value if the strings are not equal, which could be *negative* (and as non-zero will be true) if `x1` is smaller than `x2`. Either use the standard greater than operator (which is [overloaded](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp)) or check if the returned value is greater than zero:

```
return x1.compare(x2) > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in other answers, you don't call the std::string specialization, as you don't have a `std::string`, you have a `const char []`.

The best solution is to ensure that the templated method doesn't take over from the specialization. From C++17 on, I would use `if constexpr`, in C++11 and C++14, I would use `std::enable_if`. (Note that I use string_view to prevent memory allocations.)

```
template <typename T>
bool isGreater(T x1, T x2)
{
if constexpr (std::is_convertable_v<T, std::string_view>)
    std::string_view{x1}.compare(x2);
else
    return (x1 > x2);
}
```

Old standards:

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if<!std::is_convertable<T, std::string>::value>::type>
bool isGreater(T x1, T x2)
{
    return (x1 > x2);
}

bool isGreater(string x1, string x2)
{
    return (x1.compare(x2));
}
```

Comment: PS: your string variant contains a bug, I did not fix that in my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
bool isGreater(T x1, T x2)
{
    return (x1 > x2);
}

bool isGreater(string x1, string x2)
{
    return (x1.compare(x2));
}

int main()
{
    cout << isGreater(string("AAAA"), string("ZZZZ")) << endl;
    cout << isGreater(5, 10) << endl;
    string str1 = "AAAA";
    string str2 = "ZZZZ";
    cout << str1.compare(str2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You need to type cast else it is calling template